# Stuck scraping a specific table with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

So the table I'm trying to scrape can be found here: http://www.betdistrict.com/tipsters

I'm after the table titled 'June Stats'.

Here's my spider:

```
from __future__ import division
from decimal import *

import scrapy
import urlparse

from ttscrape.items import TtscrapeItem 

class BetdistrictSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "betdistrict"
allowed_domains = ["betdistrict.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.betdistrict.com/tipsters"]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//table[1]/tr'):
        item = TtscrapeItem()
        name = sel.xpath('td[@class="tipst"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
        url = sel.xpath('td[@class="tipst"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
        tipster = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' + name + '</a>'
        item['Tipster'] = tipster
        won = sel.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()[0]
        lost = sel.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract()[0]
        void = sel.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()[0]
        tips = int(won) + int(void) + int(lost)
        item['Tips'] = tips
        strike = Decimal(int(won) / tips) * 100
        strike = str(round(strike,2))
        item['Strike'] = [strike + "%"]
        profit = sel.xpath('//td[5]/text()').extract()[0]
        if profit[0] in ['+']:
            profit = profit[1:]
        item['Profit'] = profit
        yield_str = sel.xpath('//td[6]/text()').extract()[0]
        yield_str = yield_str.replace(' ','')
        if yield_str[0] in ['+']:
            yield_str = yield_str[1:]
        item['Yield'] = '<span style="color: #40AA40">' + yield_str + '%</span>'
        item['Site'] = 'Bet District'
        yield item
```

This gives me a list index out of range error on the very first variable (name).

However, when I rewrite my xpath selectors starting with //, e.g:

```
name = sel.xpath('//td[@class="tipst"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
```

The spider runs, but scrapes the first tipster over and over again.

I think it has something to do with the the table not having a thead, but containing th tags within the first tr of the tbody.

Any help is much appreciated.

----------EDIT----------

In response to Lars suggestions:

I've tried to use what you've suggested but still get a list out of range error:

```
from __future__ import division
from decimal import *

import scrapy
import urlparse

from ttscrape.items import TtscrapeItem 

class BetdistrictSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "betdistrict"
    allowed_domains = ["betdistrict.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.betdistrict.com/tipsters"]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//table[1]/tr[td[@class="tipst"]]'):
        item = TtscrapeItem()
        name = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()[0]
        url = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()[0]
        tipster = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' + name + '</a>'
        item['Tipster'] = tipster
        yield item
```

Also, I'm assuming by doing things this way, multiple for loops are required since not all cells have the same class?

I've also tried doing things without a for loop, but in that case it once again scrapes only the first tipster multiple times :s

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
name = sel.xpath('td[@class="tipst"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
```

the XPath expression starts with `td` and so is relative to the context node that you have in the variable `sel` (i.e. the `tr` element in the set of `tr` elements that the `for` loop iterates over).

However when you say

```
name = sel.xpath('//td[@class="tipst"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
```

the XPath expression starts with `//td`, i.e. select all `td` elements anywhere in the document; this is not relative to `sel`, and so the results will be the same on every iteration of the `for` loop. That's why it scrapes the first tipster over and over again.

Why does the first XPath expression fail with list index out of range error? Try taking the XPath expression one location step at a time, printing out the results, and you'll soon find the problem. In this case, it appears to be because the first `tr` child of `table[1]` does not have a `td` child (only `th` children). So the `xpath()` selects nothing, the `extract()` returns an empty list, and you try to reference the first item in that empty list, giving a list index out of range error.

To fix this, you could change your for loop XPath expression to loop only over those `tr` elements that have `td` children:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//table[1]/tr[td]'):
```

You could get fancier, requiring a `td` of the right class:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//table[1]/tr[td[@class="tipst"]]'):
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Lars. I've added an edit above since trying to implement this, but still no luck!

Comment: @preach, even though we've changed the `for` loop statement's XPath expression, `sel` still holds a `tr` element, not a `td` element. That's because XPath predicates (the stuff in square brackets) do not indicate a further location step; they just filter the `tr`s that you're already selecting. So you need to change the XPath for `name`, for example, back to `td[@class="tipst"]/a/text()` instead of just `a/text()`.